# Does Berkeley DB (Java version) support data partitioning?

Tags: java, database, store, berkeley-db, key-value

I have about 5GB data to store BDB, but I found the performance is not very good. Does it support data partitioning? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What performance are you seeing? We typically see 10s of thousands of writes per second and 100s of thousands of reads per second. Berkeley DB is one of the highest throughput key/value data storage libraries available.

If you're using Berkeley DB Java Edition, the best place to get help is in the BDB JE forum at: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=273

If you're using Berkeley DB (C library) via the Java API, the best place to get help is in the BDB forum at: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=271

Regards,

Dave